# холст всплывает только на 1 секунду

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

```
import pygame

size = width, height = (400, 300)

screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)

pygame.init()
```

Answer (score 2):

@Danis А теперь холст завис и не закрывается ;) Надо бы так:

```
import pygame

size = width, height = (400, 300)

screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)

pygame.init()

running = True

try:
    while running:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                running = False
    pygame.quit()
except SystemExit:
    pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 1):

ваша программа просто доходить до конца и завершается. Надо в конце добавить цикл `while`

```
import pygame

size = width, height = (400, 300)

screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)

pygame.init()

while True:
    pass
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1212050/%d1%85%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%81%d1%82-%d0%b2%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%bb%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%ba%d0%be-%d0%bd%d0%b0-1-%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%b4%d1%83/1212054#1212054

Comment: Чтобы работало нормально, нужен цикл обработки сообщений, а не тупо бесконечный цикл. С тем же успехом можно было `input()` в конце воткнуть (окно бы сразу не закрылось, но события окна точно так же не обрабатывались бы).

Comment: @insolor большую часть времени я пишу код на телефоне, а на нем нет разницы есть ли обработка сообщений или нет.

Comment: @Danis ну как бы все равно где вы пишите. В вопросе не указано, что код будет запускаться на телефоне, а на десктопе такой бесконечный цикл создаст зависшее окно. Не понятно зачем делать криво, и чтобы работало только у вас, вместо того чтобы посмотреть документацию и сделать нормально.